# Char has no value when printing in C

Tags: arrays, c, vertex, edges

I have this issue where I want to print the vertices and edges. I'm trying to make a BFS AND DFS when I'm done with this problem. but this time I just want to print the vertices and the edges of the graph given below as A char, but it didn't show at all, and the vertex only shows an integer instead of char. I just want the output something like this.

```
Vertices - A 
           B
           C 
           D
           E

Edges - A <----> B   // I output this on the printEdges void
        A <----> D
        B <----> C
        B <----> E
```

This is what I've tried, currently output

[image]

The problem I think, is on the char value, when I change it to the `integer` it works fine but I want the output to contain `char`, I admit I'm new in `C++` is anyone can help me?

[image]

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct vList {
  int vid;
  bool visited = false;
  struct vList *next;
};

struct eList{
    struct eList *next;
    struct vList *start, *end; //A --- B, A --- C, ...., D --- 
};

struct queue{
    struct vList *vertex;
    struct queue* next;
};


struct queue *createQueueNode(struct vList *vertex) {
  struct queue *node = (struct queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  node->vertex = vertex;
  node->next = NULL;
 
  return node;
}

struct vList *createVertex(int id) {
  struct vList *node = (struct vList *) malloc(sizeof(struct vList));
  //Your code start here
 
  node->vid = id;           // assign values
  node->next = NULL;        
 
  return node;
}

struct vList *searchVertex(struct vList *vroot, int vid){
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    //Your code start here
    while(temp != NULL){                // Loop until temp equals to NULL
        if(temp->vid == vid){           // if temp vid is equal to the item id
            return temp;                // return if found
        } else {        
            temp = temp->next;          // if not on to next vertex
        }
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

struct eList *createEdges(struct vList *root, int s, int e){
    struct vList *temps = searchVertex(root, s);
    struct vList *tempe = searchVertex(root, e);
    
    if (temps == NULL || tempe == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else {
        struct eList *edge = (struct eList *) malloc(sizeof(struct eList));
        //Your code start here
        
        edge->next = NULL;              // assign next edge to null
        edge->start = temps;            // assign start edge with found start vertex
        edge->end = tempe;              // assign end edge with found end vertex
        
        return edge;
    }
}

struct eList *addEdges(struct vList *vroot, struct eList *eroot, char s, char e){
    struct eList *t = createEdges(vroot, s, e);
    //You can improve this implementation by using Tail, thus improving also its runtime. (Optional)
    struct eList *temp = eroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return t;
    }
    else
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
        
    temp->next = t;
    
return eroot;
}

void printEdges(struct eList *eroot){
    
    struct eList *temp = eroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Empty.");
    }
    else
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("\n%i <---> %i", temp->start->vid, temp->end->vid );
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void printVertex(struct vList *vroot){
    
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Empty.");
    }
    else
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("\n%i", temp->vid );
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

struct vList *addVertex(struct vList *vroot, int vid){
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        temp = createVertex(vid);
        return temp;
    }
    else{
    
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        
        temp->next = createVertex(vid);
    }
    return vroot;
}

int main() {
struct vList *vroot = NULL; 
struct eList *eroot = NULL;


struct queue *rear = NULL, *front = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        vroot = addVertex(vroot, i);
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,'A', 'B'); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,'A', 'D'); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,'B', 'C'); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,'B', 'E'); 

    
    printf("\nVertices ");
    printVertex(vroot);
    printf("\nEdges ");
    printEdges(eroot);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And both in C and C++, there's no "null" or "empty" values. *Every* variable will have a value. It might be *indeterminate* but still have a value.

Comment: @Some programmer dude but it works fine when I used `integer` value , when the time I change the vertices and edges to char there's no  value .

Comment: Also please take this a a good opportunity to learn how to *debug* your code. More specifically how to use a *debugger* to step though the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] which ONLY creates a list of vertices, tries to output them and then fails the same way as you observe in your full code. Try to avoid the need for user input, i.e. use hardcoded initialisations.